# how to add retry times or max attemp time in powershell with O365

Tags: powershell, email, office365, exchange-server, system.net.mail

I have a script to send email via powershell, sometimes due to the bad network, the send maybe failed.

is there any way to add retry function in it?

thank you

```
$UserName = "xxx@xxx.com"      #account
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString SFDSFWSDSFSFW -AsPlainText –Force #password
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName,$Password) #password
$from = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("xxx@xxx.com", "SCM")
$TLS12Protocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType] 'Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $TLS12Protocol
        ## 1 send to V290
        ## Define the Send-MailMessage parameters
        $mailParams = @{
            SmtpServer                 = 'smtp.office365.com'
            Port                       = '587' # or '25' if not using TLS
            UseSSL                     = $true ## or not if using non-TLS
            BodyasHtml                 = $true
            Credential                 = $cred
            From                       = $from
            To                         = 'AAA@outlook.com'
            Cc                         = 'BBB@outlook.com','CCC@outlook.com'
            Subject                    = "AR Report"
            Body                       = 'Dears,'
            Attachments                = 'C:\AutoJob\xxx\Output_Files\V290.xlsx'
            Encoding                   = $encoding
        }
        Send-MailMessage @mailParams
```

it can have retry function to send the email again

Comment: Yes email will occasionally fail, but I do not think your problems is in the network.  I believe if you send the same email with same parameters it will always fail.  Some email sites will accept your parameters, and other will not.

Comment: What error do you get in the code? have you tried debugging it at least?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769476/send-mailmessage-returns-4-4-1-connection-timed-out-every-10-minutes   I meet the same issue with this guy